# Data not showing on vue.js component using laravel api

Tags: laravel, api, vue.js, vue-component

I'm trying to get the data from database using an API, but there are no output on my vue controller.

Am I doing this right?

I think I'm assigning the `scheduleList` the wrong way.

I'm very new to vue.js and API, I want to know what I'm doing wrong here.

**Controller**

```
public function schedules(){ 
    return Schedule::all(); 
}
```

**api.php**

```php
    Route::get('schedules', 'CalendarController@schedules');
```

**Vue Component**

```js
    <script>
    import axios from 'axios'
    
    export default {
    
      data() {
        return {
          schedules: [],
    
          scheduleList: [
             {
            id: schedules.id,
            title: schedules.title,
            category: schedules.category,
            start: schedules.start,
            end: schedules.end
            },
          ],
    
        };
      },
     
      methods: {
       
        loadSchedules() {
         axios.get('/api/schedules')
         .then((response) => {
           this.schedules = response.data;
         })
         
        }
      },
      mounted() {
        this.loadSchedules();
      }
    };
    </script>
    <style>
    </style>
```

Comment: How do you show that list?

Comment: I think it's because you're assigning values to `scheduleList` that don't exist yet

Comment: Im using tui.calendar. But i think the problem is how assign the value id: schedules.id. Is this the correct way?

Comment: Im getting the error ReferenceError: schedules is not defined

Comment: add your loadSchedules into a created(), then add async await to your loadSchedules function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in your data option because you're referencing `schedules` which is undefined, I'm sure that you're meaning `this.schedules` but doing that will not solve the issue because at first rendering `this.schedules` is an empty array, another problem that you're referencing at as object in `scheduleList` items using `schedules.id`, if the `schedules` property is an array i recommend the following solution :

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios'

export default {

  data() {
    return {
      schedules: [],

      scheduleList: [],

    };
  },
 
  methods: {
   
    loadSchedules() {
     axios.get('/api/schedules')
     .then((response) => {
       this.schedules = response.data;
  
      let schedule=this.schedules[0]
     
    this.scheduleList.push({
        id: schedule.id,
        title: schedule.title,
        category: schedule.category,
        start: schedule.start,
        end: schedule.end
        })

     })
     
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.loadSchedules();
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

always catch errors if you do promises.

```js
loadSchedules() {
     axios.get('/api/schedules')
     .then((response) => {
       this.schedules = response.data;
     })
     .catch(error => {
       console.log(error)
     })
```

inside your error you can better see whats going wrong.
other way is the "network" tab in your browser where you can trace your api request[image]

Comment: Yes, I'm catching errors on my original code. I just removed it so that the code is shorter here. I cant see any errors on the network tab though.

Comment: then try console.log(error.response) as output inside your catch